# How can I clear a listbox's selected item via binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox, selection, itemscontrol

I have a WPF `ListBox` bound to a collection via `ItemsSource`.
The selected item is bound to a property on the VM in two-way mode.
I want the selected item to be "unselected" on the UI when I assign a value to the model property that doesn't exist in the collection.

Is that possible? If not is there an alternative to clear the selected item?

Keep in mind I'm working in MVVM pattern so I don't have access to the list itself from the code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume the following:

1. The ItemsSource property of your listbox is bound to some list in your ViewModel (i.e. VM_List).
2. The SelectedItem property of your listbox is bound to some property in your ViewModel (i.e. VM_SelectedItem) with a TwoWay binding.

If the above is not accurate, please give a little bit more information about your implementation.

Your viewmodel should have some code that looks something like this:

```
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Student> vmlist = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
    private Student vmselecteditem;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public VM()
    {
        PropertyChanged = new PropertyChangedEventHandler(VM_PropertyChanged);
    }

    private void VM_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Student> VM_List
    {
        get
        {
            return vmlist;
        }
    }

    public Student VM_SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return vmselecteditem;
        }
        set
        {
            vmselecteditem = value;
        }
    }

    public void AddNewStudent(Student NewStudent)
    {
        VM_SelectedItem = null;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("VM_SelectedItem"));
        VM_SelectedItem = NewStudent;
        SaveStudent();
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("VM_SelectedItem"));
        //The last line is optional, if you want to select the new student just added.
    }

    private void SaveStudent()
    {
        //A fake operation to save the student.
        //To stick with MVVM, the save function should be in the model
        //And this function should just call the one in the model.
        BackgroundWorker b = new BackgroundWorker();
        b.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(b_DoWork);
        b.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(b_RunWorkerCompleted);
        b.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void AddStudentToList()
    {
        VM_List.Add(VM_SelectedItem);
    }

    private void b_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Simulating a long save operation
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }

    private void b_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddStudentToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: The two assumptions you made are correct. what i forgot to mention is that i use the vmselecteditem property for other purposes as well. i need it to have the value even if it isn`t part of the collection. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: that's interesting... in that case setting it to null is not really an option. You may want to consider having a second property that the UI is bound to for "selecting an item" like a VM_SelectedItem_UI property. VM_SelectedItem_UI would update VM_SelectedItem if and only if it is part of the collection, and vice versa. I can't really think of a better way to do it. I can post some code if you need clarification.

Comment: thanks! i understand the solution but it sounds a bit too complicated for my rather simple requirement. maybe something in my design is wrong due to my lack of experience with mvvm.
I have a list of students and a student datatemplate that is bound to a selected student property. when i select a listbox item it is bound to the same selected student which then changes the datatemplate according to the new selected student. the use case in my question is when i want to add a new student and then i need it to be a new instance which obviously isnt part of the students list.
did i miss something?

Comment: Hmm, if I understand you correctly, you want to clear the selected item before you add a new instance of student to your list? Using the example I provided, you can have a function in your ViewModel that 1) unselects the currently selected item, 2) adds the new student to the list, and 3) if you want, you can select the new student you have just added. I've updated my answer to reflect this. I'm sorry if this is not what you meant, it's sometimes hard to get on the same page via the internet.

Comment: thank you for the effort! this is not what i wanted :]
i dont want the new student to be added to the list until it is saved.
i want the new student to be referenced by the selected property and not be a part of the student list. and as i said before, while this is the case, the list should be cleared of selection

Comment: @user2035515 I've updated the solution again. I think the key is in property change notification. You can notify the UI that the selected item has changed whenever you want to. So I'm setting VM_SelectedItem to null briefly, raising event notification (this clears the selected value in the ListView), then setting it equal to the new student value, doing whatever operations I need to with it (i.e. save), and then finally raising the event again (optional, if you want to set the new student as selected). Take a look at the updated solution, and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Also an additional note, if your save operation is long, and is done on the same thread as the UI, the selected item probably won't clear while you are saving. So if you have a long save operation, it is best done on a separate thread (which is why my example has a backgroundworker).

Comment: Im sorry for your trouble but i didnt explain myself correctly.
When i said i dont want the user to be added until it is saved i meant until the user finishes to fill in all the details in the form (which ofc requiers the entity to be displayed) and clicks the save button.
I went with your suggestion of using two properties. thanks you very much!